# How can I turn off the Grub menu for Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

A quick search around the web has forum questions and answers to request that Linux boot immediately, as opposed to automatically displaying a Grub menu.

I had brief success, but for my recent efforts either none of my efforts have resulted in my computer booting immediately into Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya, or the change gets clobbered in lightning time.

How can I set Mint 18.2 (or newer) to immediately boot instead of an unprovoked Grub menu?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are running as root and open your `/etc/default/grub` file. Set the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` to 0.0 and then run

```
update-grub
```

That will stop the grub menu from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which step in this is the most critical, but I set `/etc/default/grub` to have `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` as (integer) `0`, commented out the `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` line, and ran `update-grub2`, all as root.

I'm at the moment not interested in seeing how far this can be pared down, but with thanks to [Nasir Riley's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1286240/167207) for something that appears to stick.

Comment: This seems more like a comment that Nasir's answer and Jake's comment worked rather than a new solution.  If so, it would be more appropriate to accept that answer and either add this as a comment or edit the answer to append the additional info.